# Insert one table into another table, when column header names are not in the same order

Tags: excel, vba, macos, listobject

I want to insert all the data from one table `copy_tbl` at the end of another table `paste_tbl` both in different worksheets, but in the same workbook.

The columns that have the same header name will not be in the same order in both tables, so I need to rearrange the order of the inserted data columns to match the destination.

The `copy_tbl` might have column header names that doesn't exist in `paste_tbl`, and I want those columns to be added to `paste_tbl` (this is optional and the columns that doesn't have a match in the destination table can be ignored, if it's a headache to do).

I've been trying to read up on ListObjects and also trying to code some kind of loop that matches column header names before inserting data, but I'm stuck.

This seems like a fairly simple task, and I was certain I would at least figure it out with the help of google, but I've been sitting here for 6 hours now and I'm not getting anywhere.

I did find a solution to this by using Power Query, but I'm on a Mac, and it hasn't been implemented in Excel for Mac yet :|

Is there someone willing to help me solve this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Edit:

I abandoned trying to use ListObjects and tried something else.
This is the code I've come up with so far:

```
    Dim r As Range, c As Range, msg As String
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        
    With Sheets("copy_sht").Range("1:1").CurrentRegion
        For Each r In Sheets("paste_sht").Range("1:1")
            Set c = .Rows(1).Find(r.Value, , , xlWhole, , 0)
            If Not c Is Nothing Then
                .Columns(c.Column).copy
                r.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
            Else
                msg = msg & vbLf & r.Value
            End If
        Next
        
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
                
    End With

End Sub
```

This replaces some of the values into the correct cells, and it also overwrites the whole first column with data from the second table.

This is what I want to happen:

```
╔════════════╦═══════╦═══════╦═══════╦═══════╗
║     Number ║ info1 ║ info2 ║ info3 ║ info4 ║
╠════════════╬═══════╬═══════╬═══════╬═══════╣
║          1 ║ abc   ║       ║ xyz   ║   456 ║
║          2 ║       ║ 123   ║       ║       ║
║          3 ║       ║       ║ 456   ║       ║
║          4 ║       ║       ║       ║       ║
║          5 ║ abc   ║ asd   ║ zxc   ║       ║
╚════════════╩═══════╩═══════╩═══════╩═══════╝
╔════════════╦═══════╦═══════╦═══════╦═══════╗
║     Number ║ info1 ║ info3 ║ info4 ║ info5 ║
╠════════════╬═══════╬═══════╬═══════╬═══════╣
║          1 ║ def   ║ www   ║   123 ║ a     ║
║          3 ║       ║       ║       ║ b     ║
║          5 ║       ║       ║       ║ c     ║
║          6 ║       ║       ║       ║ d     ║
║          7 ║ 123   ║       ║       ║ e     ║
╚════════════╩═══════╩═══════╩═══════╩═══════╝
╔════════════╦════════╦═══════╦════════╦════════╦═══════╗
║     Number ║ info1  ║ info2 ║ info3  ║ info4  ║ info5 ║
╠════════════╬════════╬═══════╬════════╬════════╬═══════╣
║          1 ║ abcdef ║       ║ xyzwww ║ 456123 ║ a     ║
║          2 ║        ║ 123   ║        ║        ║       ║
║          3 ║        ║       ║  456   ║        ║ b     ║
║          4 ║        ║       ║        ║        ║       ║
║          5 ║ abc    ║ asd   ║ zxc    ║        ║ c     ║
║          6 ║        ║       ║        ║        ║ d     ║
║          7 ║ 123    ║       ║        ║        ║ e     ║
╚════════════╩════════╩═══════╩════════╩════════╩═══════╝
```

The first table `paste_tbl` will become the third table after the data has been added from the second table `copy_tbl`.

This is what the code actually does with the first table:

```
╔═════════╦═══════╦═══════╦═══════╦═══════╗
║  Number ║ info1 ║ info2 ║ info3 ║ info4 ║
╠═════════╬═══════╬═══════╬═══════╬═══════╣
║       1 ║ def   ║       ║ www   ║   123 ║
║       3 ║       ║ 123   ║       ║       ║
║       5 ║       ║       ║       ║       ║
║       6 ║       ║       ║       ║       ║
║       7 ║ 123   ║ asd   ║       ║       ║
╚═════════╩═══════╩═══════╩═══════╩═══════╝
```

So what I'm still missing is:

- Adding missing columns from `copy_tbl` to `paste_tbl`.
- Making sure the data that is pasted from `copy_tbl` is matched with the same unique ID located in the first column in `paste_tbl`, and if that unique ID doesn't exist, instead paste the whole row at the bottom of the table.
- If data already exists in a destination cell,  I want to concatenate that with the data from `copy_tbl`.

---

Edit 2:
Realizing some parts of VBA I've never understand, I tried to do this the old fashioned way with formulas, and I succeeded.

It's probably not very optimized, because it takes a while to populate the table, and I was getting tired when I finished it. But it gets it done.

Sorry if it's a bit messy, but what it does is it populates a new table basen on the values of two other tables `tabell1`and `tabell2`. It merges any existing cells data with the same unique ID `$A2` which needs to be in the first column of all tables.
You have to collect all the unique ID's and place them without duplicates in the table that is to be populated. Then just paste the following formula into the first row of every column of your table.

```
=IFERROR(
IF(
      IF(
            COUNTIF(tabell1;$A2)=1;
                   VLOOKUP($A2;tabell1;MATCH(B$1;tabell1[#Headers];0);FALSE);""
            )
                     =
        IF(
                             COUNTIF(tabell2;$A2)=1;
                             VLOOKUP($A2;tabell2;MATCH(B$1;tabell2[#Headers];0);FALSE);""
            );
                   IF(
                           AND(COUNTIF(tabell1;$A2)=1;COUNTIF(tabell2;$A2)=1);
                           IFERROR(
                                 VLOOKUP($A2;tabell1;MATCH(B$1;tabell1[#Headers];0);FALSE);
                                  VLOOKUP($A2;tabell2;MATCH(B$1;tabell2[#Headers];0);FALSE));
CONCATENATE(VLOOKUP($A2;tabell1;MATCH(B$1;tabell1[#Headers];0);FALSE);" ";VLOOKUP($A2;tabell2;MATCH(B$1;tabell2[#Headers];0);FALSE)));
IF(
                             COUNTIF(tabell2;$A2)=1;
                             VLOOKUP($A2;tabell2;MATCH(B$1;tabell2[#Headers];0);FALSE);VLOOKUP($A2;tabell1;MATCH(B$1;tabell1[#Headers];0);FALSE)
            ));" ")
```

Comment: *"trying to code"*: could you provide your code? Could you also provide a concrete but simple example of such pair of tables, which demonstrate the problem?

Comment: added some more info and the code that I've come up with so far.